# order items that are group of two on display flex

Tags: css, sass

Im trying to make the next grid of elements using flex on desk:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

they are group of two items per container like this:

```
<div class="descriptionElements">
                <div class="itemsContainer">
                    <div class="itemDescription">
                        <div class="descriptionItemSection">
                            <span class="titleItemDescription">item-1</span>
                            <p class="textItemDescription">Description
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="itemDescription">
                        <div class="descriptionItemSection">
                            <span class="titleItemDescription">item-2</span>
                            <p class="textItemDescription">Description
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="itemsContainer">
                    <div class="itemDescription">
                        <div class="descriptionItemSection">
                            <span class="titleItemDescription">item-3</span>
                            <p class="textItemDescription">description
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemDescription">
                        <div class="descriptionItemSection">
                            <span class="titleItemDescription">item-4</span>
                            <p class="textItemDescription">Description
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Why do this?, be cause on mobile I need to do a different order of items over a slider, something like this:

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

I know that if I make a simple container with each item, I can order like the first example, but I cannot order like I want on mobile, or yes?

about the slider, im using slick slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard flexbox this is not possible. However, you could open up the individual wrapper divs with `display: contents` and then it should work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.descriptionElements {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.itemsContainer {
  display: contents;
}

.itemDescription {
  width: 33.333%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="descriptionElements">
  <div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="itemDescription">
      <div class="descriptionItemSection">
        <span class="titleItemDescription">item-1</span>
        <p class="textItemDescription">Description
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="itemDescription">
      <div class="descriptionItemSection">
        <span class="titleItemDescription">item-2</span>
        <p class="textItemDescription">Description
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="itemDescription">
      <div class="descriptionItemSection">
        <span class="titleItemDescription">item-3</span>
        <p class="textItemDescription">description
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemDescription">
      <div class="descriptionItemSection">
        <span class="titleItemDescription">item-4</span>
        <p class="textItemDescription">Description
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>






    <div class="itemsContainer">
      <div class="itemDescription">
        <div class="descriptionItemSection">
          <span class="titleItemDescription">item-5</span>
          <p class="textItemDescription">description
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemDescription">
        <div class="descriptionItemSection">
          <span class="titleItemDescription">item-6</span>
          <p class="textItemDescription">Description
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the grid is fixed than you can you use :nth-child to pick even and odd elements, more about this pseudo selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
.demo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 210px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.demo li {
  flex: 1 33.3333%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000 inset;
}

.demo li:nth-child(even) {
  order: 2;
}
.demo li:nth-child(odd) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="demo">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```